# making matrix using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to make a matrix with 5 rows and 4 columns. The problem is when I run it there appears an error that "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yasini\Desktop\30.py", line 21, in 
    ['ART|Ф',0.71], ['N|Ф',0.29], ['V|Ф',0.0001], ['P|Ф',0]]).reshape(5,4)
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged".

How can I solve it?

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([['ART|ART',0], ['N|ART',1], ['V|ART',0], ['P|ART',0],
     ['ART|N',0.0001], ['N|N',0.13], ['V|N',0.43], ['P|N',0.44],
     ['ART|V',0.65], ['N|V',0.35], ['V|V',0.0001], ['P|V',0.0001],
     ['ART|P',0.74], ['N|P',0.26], ['V|P',0.0001], ['P|P',0.0001],
     ['ART|Ф',0.71], ['N|Ф',0.29], ['V|Ф',0.0001], ['P|Ф',0]]).reshape(5,4)
print (A)
```

Comment: The error tells you the problem, why do you ask us? Your initial array has 20*2=40 elements, and you want to reshape it into a 5*4=20 element array.

Comment: Because the matrix you are creating does not have 5 rows and 4 columns. You need to remove some of these: [ ]

Comment: When I omit the zero from the last cell (['P|Ф',0]), it works right and a 5*4 matrix is produced but when I add zero again this error occurs

Comment: print your "matrix" and you'll see it is not what you think! A "matrix" is 2d and what you get is a sort of ill defined 3d array... (each cell contains a list with 2 elements, except the last which has only 1)

Comment: Maybe sharing the desired output would help since you seem to be confused with the number of dimensions...

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `reshape` step and print `A.shape`.  How many items are there in `A`?  If there aren't 4*5=20, then reshape to `(5,4)` will produce this error.  When a step gives you an error, make sure the previous one produced what you expected.

My guess is that the shape is (20,2), and dtype is string (or maybe object).  It isn't the 20 pairs of `('str',int)` tuples that you expect.

Why are you mixing names and numbers in one array?

Comment: I need them for tagging the sentences (in nlp). theses numbers are the probabilities of tags. first I made a matrix just of numbers. and then because I couldn't add headings (tags) to the matrix, I brought them into the matrix to assign each number to its tag.

Comment: Put labels in separate lists.